# phpmyadmin Error on GoDaddy shared hosting - Script timeout passed, if you want to finish import, please resubmit the same file

Tags: godaddy, database, phpmyadmin, import, timeout

I have a database named **A**. I want to export it, and import it to a new database **B**.

I exported the **A**, no issues. While trying to import to the new database B, I faced the following error:

> Script timeout passed, if you want to finish import, please resubmit
>   the same file and import will resume

I am using shared hosting environment in GoDaddy. I contacted them. They told me that they were able to export and import successfully, and the problem can be related to my internet connection.

On other sites, they are suggesting to modify the below section in config.

> $cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 300

I don't think I can fix by changing since it is a shared hosting environment plus also I believe the file I am trying to import is not that much big to receive a timeout. So I am not really sure if this is the root cause really.

I also tried to use "copy database" under operations tab in phpmyadmin. This is also not working. Resubmitting the file also didn't work. What do you suggest ?

Comment: Can you SSH into GoDaddy's server and run the import and export on the command line?

Comment: Importing data using phpmyadmin is limited regardless of what you do. You can only import so much. The suggestion to shell in is one suggestion that should certainly work. Another is to install MySQL Workbench found here and try that. https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/ Either way, you will need to get into the nuts and bolts of MySQL for self preservation instead of relying upon phpmyadmin. It is a good app for a quick thing here and there, but not recommended over Workbench.

Answer (score -1):

Go to `C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries` and change `$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 300` to `0`

**Like this:**

```
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 300
```

**Change To**

```
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0
```

try it i hope it will work

Comment: The question says they are using shared hosting, so they don't have their own server running XAMP.   They also say they have seen this proposed solution elsewhere, but they don't think they can do it on shared hosting.